# Changing size of the components of JPanel depending on the size of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

In most of the GUI programs, when the user resizes it, the components of the program, such as text fields, buttons, etc. tend to increase or decrease their size depending on the decisions of the user. I'm trying to implement this idea into my GUI program. I'm a little bit lost about how I can do it. By the way, I created my program without the usage/help of the Eclipse Swing or Netbeans' GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CodeReviewerFrame extends JFrame {
    EditorAreaPanel display = new EditorAreaPanel();
    // FileOptionsPanel fileOptionsPanel = new FileOptionsPanel( display );
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public CodeReviewerFrame(String title) throws IOException {

        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 1000));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
        setIconImage(img.getImage());

        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new HomeOptionsPanel(display), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        p.add(new NewCommentPanel(display), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(new CommentOptionsPanel(display), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        add(p, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new FileExplorerPanel(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        panel.add(new FileOptionsPanel(display), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(new CommentShowPanel(display), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);

        /**
         * Everything Under This is experimental
         */
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        //add ( fileOptionsPanel, constraints );
    }
}
```

There are components on each Panel that have been added, such as buttons in HomeOptionsPanel, huge JTextArea in the center of FileOptionsPanel plus four buttons up on the JTextArea, etc. Should I use new Layout type, or commands known as "repaint/revalidate," or implement changeListener? And should I only implement the code to the JFrame, or do it for each of the JPanels?

Comment: `EditorAreaPanel display = new EditorAreaPanel();` 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) `Everything Under This is ..` ..pointless, given a) it is never used & b) certainly not in a `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your UI upon window resizing depends (also) on the Layout Manager you are using.

Some Layout Managers (like `BorderLayout`) resize the components when the windows is resized, while others (like `FlowLayout`) don't.

It is not clear what LM you are using inside your panels, but most likely your issue stands in there.

Comment: My JFrame is set to BorderLayout, and whenever the size of it changes, it changes the sizes of the JPanels, but not the contents/components of the JPanels, such as Button, JTextArea, etc.

Comment: What do you set as Layout Manager inside each JPanel? It would be useful to provide their code, too.

Comment: **HomeOptionsPanel:** FlowLayout
**NewCommentPanel:** FlowLayout
**CommentOptionsPanel:** FlowLayout
**FileExplorerPanel:** BorderLayout
**FileOptionsPanel:** FlowLayout
**CommentShowPanel:** FlowLayout

Comment: Use BorderLayout in your panels, too (or another layout manager that actually resizes the components)